# How to port a symfony project code from a Linux to Windows server

Tags: symfony-1.4

I've a Project in Symfony 1.4.5. It was configured previously on a Linux VPS.
Need to run it on my localhost Windows machine, using Apache locally.
I'm lost. Which configuration files should be changed to achieve this ?

Comment: Have you **tried** it without any changes?

Comment: Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\testphp\ibear\config/../lib/vendor/symfony/current/lib/autoload/sfCoreAutoload.class.php' (include_path='.;C:\php\pear') in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\testphp\ibear\config\ProjectConfiguration.class.php on line 5

Comment: Try to re-`dump-autoload` with composer: `composer dump-autoload`. Not sure though.

Comment: Have you checked if the `lib/vendor/symfony` got downloaded with your project and if it is complete? You can try to download the framework files again.